# WKWebView using loadHTMLString:baseURL: api, WKURLSchemeTask not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview, custom-scheme-url

WKWebViewConfiguration:

```
[configuration setURLSchemeHandler:self forURLScheme:@"wkpath"];
```

WKWebView:

```
NSString *html = @"\
    <html><body>   \
    <script src=\"wkpath://script\"/>  \
    <img src=\"wkpath://image\"/>      \
    </body></html>";

[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseURL];
```

Delegate

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView startURLSchemeTask:(id <WKURLSchemeTask>)urlSchemeTask {
   // <script> url task never enter
   // <img> url task have enter
}
```

guess WebKit internal reasons.

refer WebKit Source Code:
https://github.com/wzw19890321/WebKit2/blob/eaa1f907695d6b0f6fd0e6e299c417a4f05cccf3/WebProcess/Network/WebLoaderStrategy.cpp#L202

Comment: Whats the issue BTW??

Comment: <script> tag task never callback.

Comment: <img> tag task is normal work